# Woocommerce: Displaying product weight on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display product weight on cart page:

I've come so far:

```
<td class="product-weight">
   <?php
     echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_weight', WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight);
   ?>
 </td><!-- /.product-weight -->
```

This piece of code will display the total weight of cart but I want weight of individual product.

Any help would be appreciated. Reference URL: [Link](http://isotopethemes.com/wp-test/?page_id=6) [plz add few products]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this :

```
global $woocommerce;

if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values )
    {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $weight = $_product->weight; echo $weight;
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

```
<td class="product-weight">
<?php
     echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_weight', $_product->get_weight());
?>
</td><!-- /.product-weight -->
```

Comment: it does not work as well, maybe I should add something to the code, the piece of code I've pasted above is inside a <td></td>. Thank you for answering Rohil.

Comment: I am trying to display weight of each product on cart page

Comment: First of all tell me does my code output anything ? can you replace `echo $weight` with `echo $weight."Its working !";` ? and thn tell me what does it give ?

Comment: Works like a Charm. Where did you find this variable, I searched all over in the API docs, I could not find it?

Comment: You can find it [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_weight).

Comment: Ah, I did go to this page, saw that function but just though it wasn't that easy, Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: @chandan 1) in which page should I copy this code? In funtions.php or in style.css? 2) should I try only the one after **Edited**?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. **It is not tested**.

```
global $woocommerce;

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $item_id => $values ) {

        $_product = $values['data'];
        $weight = $_product->weight;

        }
```