# Display the weight of each cart items in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and I'm trying to display the product weight for each product on cart page.

I have used this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'myprefix_cart_extra_info');
function myprefix_cart_extra_info() {
    global $woocommerce;
    echo '<div class="cart-extra-info">';
    echo '<p class="total-weight">' . __('Total Weight:', 'woocommerce');
    echo ' ' . $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit');
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

It display the total cart weight. I would like to also show the weight of each item in the cart as well.

How to display the product weight of each item on cart page?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce: Displaying product weight on cart page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024394/woocommerce-displaying-product-weight-on-cart-page)

Comment: @nemus Not a duplicate …

Answer (score 7):

There is multiple ways to do it. You can use the custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_get_item_data`** filter hook to display the product weight of each cart items:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'displaying_cart_items_weight', 10, 2 );
function displaying_cart_items_weight( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    $item_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();
    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'       => __('Weight', 'woocommerce'),
        'value'     => $item_weight,
        'display'   => $item_weight . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit')
    );

    return $item_data;
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### To get the total cart item weight:

To get the total cart line item weight (product weight x product quantity) simply replace:

```
$item_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();
```

by:

```
$item_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight() * $cart_item['quantity'];
```

---

Reference: [Class WC_Product::get_weight()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_weight)

Comment: Can someone tell me what $item_data and $cart_item contains? Can I use this code in my functions.php file?

Comment: I want to display some other variable in the cart but I think I am looking for this functionality only. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this in functions.php file?